# Navigation bar changes upon returning to previous VC

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm having a few issues with my navigation bar styling. Let's say I have two view controllers.

VC 1 has an orange bar with white text that I have set up like so:

```
   func stylingStuffs(){
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.38, blue: 0.24, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.38, blue: 0.24, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

VC 2 has a transparent navigation bar and the code for that is:

```
func stylingStuffs(){
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.38, blue: 0.24, alpha: 0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.38, blue: 0.24, alpha: 0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

When I navigate from VC1 to VC2 everything works fine, when I navigate from VC2 to VC1, VC1's Navbar is now white/transparent as well as the status bar.

How can I fix this or I guess reset the styles upon return to VC1?

Comment: You are confused because there is actually only one navigation bar. It is part of the one navigation controller that both view controllers are in.

Comment: Yes you have to reset the styles when returning to vc1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first view **VC 1** controller `viewDidAppear` call  `stylingStuffs()`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)

    stylingStuffs()
}
```

**@rmaddy** comment

> You are confused because there is actually only one navigation bar. It is part of the one navigation controller that both view controllers are in

so need to reset navigation bar style for VC 1

Comment: @Kingalione UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetricsDefault)